# System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile not downloading

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm trying to download files from my server through android using xamarin and I have no error but I don't find any file where it is supposed to be.

I'm using that code:

```
       System.Net.WebClient Client = new System.Net.WebClient();


        Console.WriteLine("Start downloading...");
        try
        {
            var documentsFolder = System.Environment.GetFolderPath (System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
            if(!File.Exists(documentsFolder))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(documentsFolder);
            var fileNameAndPath = Path.Combine (documentsFolder, "tmpfile");

            Client.DownloadFile(new Uri(url), fileNameAndPath);
        }
        catch(System.Exception e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
            while(e.InnerException!=null)
            {
                e=e.InnerException;
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("...end downloading");
```

There's no error catched but no file downloaded, I tried several special paths but none seems to work. Can someone help me ?

Comment: The DownloadFile method downloads to a local file data from the URI specified by in the address parameter. This method blocks while downloading the resource. To download a resource and continue executing while waiting for the server's response, use one of the DownloadFileAsync methods.

Comment: I have the same problem with DownloadFileAsync